# How to read the events when there is a change in AD?

Tags: typescript, events, azure-active-directory

I have added or modified users in my Azure active directory. how to trigger an event when there is a change in AD?

Comment: Please elaborate the Qns. How you're creating the tiggers for any modifications/additions in Azure ADby using portal or any scripts?

Comment: Hi Venkat, I have tried using this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery#configuring-the-azure-event-hub
i am able to get the events via an API , but I have to get auto trigger events . can I follow the answer u have provided below.

Comment: Yes. follow my answer to trigger the alert.

Comment: Hi Venkat, thank you for immediate reply. Here the notifications is to be received by my nest application. I have used app registration to get the notifications. how to listen to these events via application. please mention

Comment: Hi Bhavani, kindly raise a different query with proper details in this platform for latest ask in the last comment so that community members can try to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to trigger the Alerts if any addition in Azure AD:**

I created **LOG ANALYTICS WORKSPACE**, like below.

**Azure Portal > Log Analytics workspaces > Create.**

[image]

Connect your **Log Analytics workspaces** to **Azure Active Directory**.

**Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Diagnostic settings > Add diagnostic setting**

[image]

**Created notification for triggering Alerts**

**Azure Portal > Monitor > Alerts > Create > Alert Rule > Select your Subscription > Filter by resource type section add your Log Analytics workspaces**.

[image]

**Condition Section > Select Custom log search > Add your Query based your requirement(For all Activity : Add query : **AuditLogs**)**

The below query will dispaly (add member to role, Update user, Change password). details in Azure AD.

```
AuditLogs 
| project OperationName, username = parse_json(dynamic_to_json(InitiatedBy))["user"]["userPrincipalName"]
| summarize opname = count() by OperationName, tostring(username)
| render barchart
```

**Action** section create **Action group** with email, once create the action group select same Action group.

[image]

**Details** section add required details, like below

[image]

If you add member to role, Update user, change password in Azure AD, you will get the notification to tour email.

[image]

**Alerts Triggered in Portal**

[image]